# Mead keeps separating... HELP!

Tags: fermentation, mead

I just created a pomagranate mead and now it is separating it's self...
Ingredients:

- 49 oz pomagranate Puree
- 6 lbs Clover Honey
- 2 tsp Acid Blend
- 3 tsp Yeast Nutrient
- 1 tsp Pectic Enzyme
- 1 tsp Grape Tannin
- 5 tablets Campden Tablets
- 5 grams Cote de Blanc Wine Yeast

What should I do? I tried mixing the solution by shaking it... It come together but about an hour later separates into two again.

There isn't any airlock action either...

Comment: Any water in this recipe? And why so much Campden Tablets? I wonder if with just 5 grams of yeast if it will ferment at all.

Answer (score 1):

Once fermentation starts, convection currents will ensure that the puree and water are well mixed.

There was probably no need for Campden, since all the ingredients were sterile. As it stands, you've got around 300ppm of sulphur in the must, which will likely impede fermentation. Leave it under an airlock for three or four days. If fermentation has not started, add a 15g more yeast.

Answer (score 0):

Leave it be. Don't worry. Wait 3 days and then see.

As pointed in comments, there might be a lot of sulphur in it. Agitating it may help release it, and shouldn't hurt. Either way, don't repitch for few days, both to give it time to release, and to give original yeast time to start.

Things like what you did will separate, there is hardly anything you could do to avoid it. And nothing you really should. At the end, you want all the taste in solution, but all the solids settled down. And you indeed are on the good way to achieve this. If yeast are at te bottom now, then once they'll start, their own gas production will move them up (with some of material).

Comment: Is it possible that I killed the yeast and it sunk to the bottom because there is absolutely no airlock action... should I re add the yeast?  Also I didn't add any campden tablet that was for later in the recipe

Comment: @user12899 how long does it sit there? If less than 3-4 days, do nothing. Re pitching might be needed but don't hurry with it to much.

Comment: If it's too much sulphur, sometimes agitating can help draw some of the sulphur out. It will still have a somewhat sulfite aftertaste though no matter what you do at this point.

Comment: @Escoce good point. Missed amount of sulphur.

Comment: I made a banana wine once about 25 years ago. I used too much sulphite in the process end to end. Not Camden tabs, but powdered sodium meta-bisulphate. I used it for pre-batch sanitizing, for sulphiting the must and then also for sanatizing all racking gear and the final bottles. Still in entered the wine in the state fair competition, and although I lost without any ribbons for that batch, the judges comment was "this would have been best in show if not for being over sulphited". So I am rather sensitive to it now and I err on the side of too little since then.

Answer (score 0):

You might have inadvertently set up an unhealthy environment in your must. Certain store bought cider, puree, and juice products are processed using potassium sorbate to extend their shelf life by inhibiting the growth of certain molds, yeast and bacteria. Always look at the ingredients to be sure that isn't the case with what you are planning to buy.

Also known as "wine stabilizer", potassium sorbate produces sorbic acid when added to wine. It serves two purposes. When active fermentation has ceased and the wine is racked for the final time after clearing, potassium sorbate will render any surviving yeast incapable of multiplying. Yeast living at that moment can continue fermenting any residual sugar into CO2 and alcohol, but when they die no new yeast will be present to cause future fermentation. When a wine is sweetened before bottling, potassium sorbate is used to prevent re-fermentation when used in conjunction with potassium metabisulfite(Campden tablets). It is primarily used with sweet wines, sparkling wines, and some hard ciders but may be added to table wines which exhibit difficulty in maintaining clarity after fining.

Some molds and yeasts are able to detoxify sorbates by decarboxylation, producing piperylene. The pentadiene manifests as a typical odor of kerosene or petroleum.